# How do I convert an Armadillo matrix to cube?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, armadillo

I'm trying to recreate the following Python numpy code:

```
num_rows, num_cols = data.shape
N = 4
data = data.reshape(N, num_rows/N, num_cols)
```

in C++ using Armadillo matrices and cubes? How can this be done most efficiently. I dont think the resize/reshape operations are supported directly for moving from a 2d matrix to 3d cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since armadillo uses column major ordering of data (in contrast to numpy which relies on row major ordering), simply putting the matrix into a cube with 1 slice and reshaping it will produce different result (the matrix `B` below). An alternative might be to construct the slices manually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main(){

    const arma::uword N = 2;
    const arma::uword num_rows = 4;
    const arma::uword num_cols = 3;

    arma::mat A(num_rows, num_cols, arma::fill::randu);

    std::cout << A;

    arma::cube B(num_rows, num_cols, 1);
    B.slice(0) = A;
    B.reshape(num_rows/N, num_cols, N);
    std::cout << B;

    arma::cube C(num_rows/N, num_cols, N);
    for(arma::uword i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        C.slice(i) = A.rows(i*N, (i+1)*N-1);
    }
    std::cout << C;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering the effort that goes into this it almost feels to me that its better to work with 2d matrices itself. Thats why I just converted my 3d slicing operations to 2d itself.

Answer (score 2):

The *fastest* way to construct such a cube is to use one of the [advanced constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube). These allow you to directly create a new object from an arbitrary section of memory, even without copying any of the data. This is closest in spirit to the way NumPy does reshaping, in which a *view* of the original data is returned, rather than a copy.

You'd use the constructor like so:

```
// Assuming a is an arma::mat.
int N = 4;
arma::cube c(a.memptr(), N, a.n_rows / N, a.n_cols, false);
```

This takes the memory directly from `a`, without copying, and uses it as `c`'s data.

Of course, this is fast, but dangerous. You are responsible for guaranteeing that the pointed-to memory is valid as long as `c` is around. This means that the lifetime of `c` must be strictly nested in the lifetime of `a`. This can be hard to ensure, especially when `a` and `c` are both created on the heap.

You can also allow `c` to *copy* `a`'s data, by leaving off the last argument or setting it to `true`. This takes more time than the no-copy constructor, but probably less than assigning each slice from `a`'s data, since this constructor does a single bulk `memcpy` of the underlying data.

All of this is subject to the row- vs. column-major point brought up by @ewcz's answer. Make sure you know what you get when you reshape, especially if you're using the advanced constructors.

Comment: using the constructor is tempting, but I think that it won't be applicable in this case - `data.reshape(N, num_rows/N, num_cols)` essentially creates `N` slices by dividing the rows of `data` into `N` groups. Since armadillo stores data in column-major fashion, such slices won't be contiguous in memory, one needs to do some "reshuffling". The constructor approach would be applicable for something like `data.reshape(N, num_rows, num_cols/N)`, i.e., splitting the matrix in "column" space...

Comment: @tangy That was the point of my last comment. You'd need to work with the transpose of the original array, because Armadillo uses column-major ordering and NumPy uses row-major. But if you know how to slice to get what you want, this constructor will be significantly faster.

Comment: I did try that - I transposed the matrix and then applied the code from above - it still did not work. In fact based on some other answers related to armadillo I had tried this method earlier both with and without transpose- didnt work